# Why does Diphenylamine only react with the deoxyribose of purines?

Tags: biochemistry, dna

The deoxyribose in DNA in the presence of acid forms β-hydroxylevulinaldehyde which reacts with diphenylamine to give a blue color with a sharp absorption maximum at 595nm.

In DNA, only the deoxyribose of the purine nucleotides react with Diphenylamine, so that the value obtained represents half of the total deoxyribose present.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Why not start with researching what happens when DNA (not just the deoxyribose part) is placed in acidic solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have correctly stated, the DNA cannot directly react with diphenylamine. First, it has to be *cleaved* so that the deoxyribose is exposed. In acidic solution and at high temperature, a depurination occurs several orders of magnitude faster than depyrimidination, because N-7 of the purine can be protonated and assist the cleavage.

See [this mechanism](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26659789_Studies_on_the_hydrolytic_stability_of_2%27-fluoroarabinonucleic_acid_2%27F-ANA) of the acid-catalyzed depurination:

[image: Acid-catalyzed depurination]